# Is there any advantage in my creating ICommands in my ViewModel constructor?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have seen two different suggestions so far. I am not sure if they are the same or if one is the more simple and better to use.

Create in the constructor

```
public SessionViewModel()   
{   
    LikeCommand = new Command(ApplyLike);   
}  
public ICommand LikeCommand {get;private set;}
```

Create in the body of the ViewModel

```
public SessionViewModel()   
{   
}

private ICommand likeCommand;
public ICommand LikeCommand => likeCommand ?? (likeCommand = new Command(() => ApplyLike()));
```

The second way seems more complicated but does it offer advantages?

Comment: Field Initializers run at the beginning of the ctor - same stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer the next way:

```
public ICommand LikeCommand { get; }  

public SessionViewModel()   
{   
    LikeCommand = new Command(ApplyLike);   
}
```

It is different from both of the examples above, since it is a `read only auto property`. This way the `Command` will be **immutable** (not changeable), which in another words will expose less possibilities to mess up the code. I find it easier to read and understand, since the only place you can expect to initialise the command is the constructor.

Comment: Why not just:             public ICommand LikeCommand { get; }  = new Command(ApplyLike);                ...?

Comment: That's also an option, but sometimes you have other dependencies that should be instantiated and passed to the command itself.

Comment: Like?... Please without breaking MVVM.... btw my solution will works better for that need as it evaluates later than during construction (actually on first use -> Lazy like)

Comment: Like when you deal with field validation and etc.

Comment: And how does that require to instanciate a command in the ctor?

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/yuv4ik/XFFirebaseAuthExample/blob/master/XFFirebaseAuthExample/ViewModels/LoginViewModel.cs

Comment: Actually, it demonstrate that you don't need it in the ctor :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, what am I missing? It is cause of `propChangedCallBack`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Same s... stuff :)
try:

```
public abstract class VmBase
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ICommand> map = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();
    protected ICommand RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute, [CallerMemberName] string key = null)
    {
        if (!map.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            map.Add(new /*Relay or any ICommand impl*/Command(execute, canExecute));
        }
        return map[key];
    }
}

public class MyVm : VmBase
{
    public ICommand RunSomething => RelayCommand(() => { /*ApplyLike code goes here*/ }, () => true);
}
```

This allows you also interactions like "refresh all command states" and better generic cleanup access to all commands.

**Important note**: this is prototype code, not productive as this should include more checks, etc :)

Comment: There is no RelayCommand available in Xamarin.Forms, please share the code or mention the 3rd part lib.

Comment: Use Command instead of RelayCommand - or whichever implementation of ICommand you use.